How to do Client-Side Data Validation Before Using Server Actions with useActionStatus
I have been researching this question for quite a while but always find methods that validate data on the server side, pass those validations back to the form, and then display the messages on the form. However, I don’t like this approach. I want to validate the data on the client side before sending it to server actions.
Note: I don’t want validation in server actions because I’m using a NestJS backend API, so server-side validation can be handled by the APIs.
I have solved it with the React query but I'm still looking forward if I can do it using the useActionStatus or built-in APIs:
useAddNewCard
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { toast } from 'react-hot-toast';

import paymentService from '@/services/payment.service';

const useAddNewCard = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const { mutate: addNewCard, isPending: isAdding } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: paymentService().addNewCard,
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      router.push(data.url);
    },
    onError: (err) => toast.error(err.message),
  });

  return { isAdding, addNewCard };
};
export default useAddNewCard;

Helper method
export const handleClientAction = <Args extends any[], Success>(
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  asyncFn: (...args: Args) => Promise<{ success?: Success; error?: string }>
) => {
  return async (...args: Args): Promise<Success> => {
    const filteredArguments = args.filter((item) => {
      const isObj = item instanceof Object;
      if (isObj && 'queryKey' in item) {
        return false;
      }
      if (isObj && 'meta' in item) return false;
      return true;
    }) as Args;
    const { success, error } = await asyncFn(...filteredArguments);
    if (success !== undefined) return success;
    throw new Error(error || 'An unknown error occurred');
  };
};

Service
const addNewCard = handleClientAction(addNewCardAction);

Server actions
export const handleAsyncAction = <Args extends any[], Result>(
  asyncFn: (...args: Args) => Promise<Result>
) => {
  return async (
    ...args: Args
  ): Promise<{ error?: string; success?: Result }> => {
    try {
      const success = await asyncFn(...args);
      return { success };
    } catch (error: any) {
      return { error: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred' };
    }
  };
};

export const addNewCardAction = handleAsyncAction(
  async (requestData: AddNewCardRequestType) => {
    const res: Response = await fetch(
      `${process.env.BACKEND_BASE}/payments/authorization`,
      {
        method: REQUEST_METHODS.POST,
        headers: {
          ...getJsonTypeHeader(),
          ...getNodeRequiredRequestHeaders(),
          ...getAuthorizationHeader(),
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(requestData),
      }
    );
    if (!res.ok) {
      const errorResponse = await getApiError(res);
      throw new Error(errorResponse.error);
    }
    const data: AddNewCardResponseType = await res.json();
    return data;
  }
);

